# How do you get a user's real IP in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a website that collects IPs so that I can verify them for a game and so that they can't bypass a ban, but I'm not sure how to collect a user's IP from a web request using Javascript, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score -1):

Your web server would track which IP addresses are accessing it, so you could capture it there.

For javascript though there's a few suggestions on SO already:

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript)